# PROD v Test different: Deleting Accounts with Orders

Tags: unit-test, order

[Salesforce doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.account_del.htm&type=5) states when you delete an Account, its children orders are deleted

But: If you do this in an org with a real Account and a *draft* Order, when you delete the Account, you get this error:

```
Your attempt to delete MyAccount could not be completed 
because it is associated with the following orders.: 00433894
```

So, for sake of argument, let's assume the doc is wrong

Now, here is where it gets weird...

Consider an APEX testmethod that deletes an *Org* Account w/ Order

```
@IsTest (SeeAllData=true)
static void testAccountDeleteWithOrgOrder() {
    Database.DeleteResult[] results = 
       Database.delete(new List<Account> {new Account(Id='0016300000eqXLkAAM')},false);
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'results='+results);
}
```

The delete fails (just like a delete from the UI) with results showing:

```
Database.DeleteResult[getErrors=(Database.Error[getFields=();
    getMessage=Your attempt to delete 1563488920160 could not be completed 
    because it is associated with the following orders.: 00433894
```

Same thing as above happens if you run the `Database.delete` code in anonymous Apex.

But if your testmethod mocks the Accounts and child Order (as one would normally do)

```
@IsTest
static void testAccountDeleteWithMockOrder() {

    Account a = new Account(Name = 'mockAccount');
    insert a;

    Order o = new Order(AccountId = a.Id, EffectiveDate = Date.today(), Status = 'Draft');
    insert o;

    Database.DeleteResult[] results = Database.delete(new List<Account> {a},false);
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'results='+results);
}
```

Here, in the testmethod with mocked Accounts and Orders, **the delete succeeds !?!**

```
results=(Database.DeleteResult[getErrors=();getId=0016300000vIQUjAAO;isSuccess=true;])
```

Why doesn't the testmethod (V50) behave the same as PROD (also V50)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why is this important? Well, if you're writing a testmethod that is attempting to test partial success saves on Account deletion, you can't just mock Accounts and draft Orders, you need a different technique to get the partial save success.

Things I tried:

| Action | Result |
| --- | --- |
| Adding OrderItems to the mocked Order | Account still deletes |
| Adding Assets to the Account | Account still deletes |
| Activating the Order | Account fails to delete ; partial save success can be tested! |
| Adding a Case to the Account | Account fails to delete ; partial save success can be tested! |

*Note that activating an Order requires the Order to have OrderItems.*

So, the simplest solution is probably to mock a Case as child to the Account

```
@IsTest
static void testAccountDeleteWithMockCase() {

  Account a = new Account(Name = 'mockAccount', RecordTypeId = Accounts.ID_RT_B2C);
  insert a;

  Case cs = new Case(AccountId = a.Id);
  insert cs;

  Database.DeleteResult[] results = Database.delete(new List<Account> {a},false);
  System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'results='+results);
}
```